# How to comment a block of code in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, editing

In Emacs, how to comment a block of text, i.e. how to indent a block of text rightward by `n` whitespace characters and put a chosen character sequence, say `##`, at the beginning of each line?

Original

```
foo
bar foobar
   foo bar
```

Desired:

```
# foo
# bar foobar
#    foo bar
```

- I need a method that doesn't interfere with CUA mode.
- `comment-dwin` doesn't allow me to choose arbitrary character sequence.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way is to use `string-rectangle` (`C-x r t`).

Mark the block, then call `string-rectangle` and give `##` as a string to insert.

Comment: Here are more concrete steps: 1) move cursor to beginning 2) `C-M-@` 3) move cursor to end 4) `C-x r t` 5) type prefix character sequence, such as `## `, press `ENT`

Comment: is it also possible to do the inverse?

Comment: You can select a rectangle and delete it with `C-x R K`

Answer (score 11):

Depending on what mode you are running (e.g. CC Mode, Lisp Mode) you can select the region and then use the command `comment-region` (usually bound to C-c C-c.  If everything is set correctly, it should use the appropriate comment characters for the type of file you are editing.

Comment: How is this different from `M-;`?

Comment: @duperuser `M-;` is a more general commenting command.  When there is no active region, it inserts a comment (after any statements on the line, and lined up with the comment column).  When a region is selected, it behaves like `comment-region`.  When there is no active region, `comment-region` does not insert a comment.

Comment: Not only that, but `comment-region`, unlike `comment-dwim` (which is `M-;` by default) lets you flexibly nest and **unnest** block comments. Use plain **`C-u`** to unnest one level of nesting. (I bind **`C-x C-;`** to `comment-region`. Actually, I bind it to **`comment-region-lines`** from [`misc-cmds.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/misc-cmds.el).)

Answer (score 9):

You want to select the code region and then `M-;`

Comment: The best and simple emacs way answer.